# different compare signature for std::upper_bound and std::lower_bound

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14, std

Here is a sample example for both `std::lower_bound` & `std::upper_bound`, notice the signature of Compare lambda being passed to them -

```
const auto lower_x = std::lower_bound(
          points.begin(), points.end(), rec.min_corner.x,

          [](const RankedPoint &rp, const double x) { return rp.point.x < x; });

const auto upper_x = std::upper_bound(
          points.begin(), points.end(), rec.max_corner.x,

          [](const double x, const RankedPoint &rp) { return x < rp.point.x; });
```

What is the possible reasoning behind keeping the signature exact opposite of each other? I wasn't aware of this and gcc compiled (clang didn't) it when I used `auto` instead of definite types with wrong signatures. Costed me 10 minutes of frustration.

Comment: Because the comparison function's semantic must be "less than `<`".

Comment: Ranges library would allow projection to remove this issue :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The custom comparator versions of `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` are generalizations of simply using `<`. `lower_bound` yields the first element that is not less than `value`, so the check that happens is `elem < value` (or `!(elem < value)` really). `upper_bound` yields the first element *greater* than `value`, but we instead of writing `elem > value` (which would require `operator>`), we just flip the ordering to `value < elem`. This maintains the sole requirement of `operator<`, but as a result, the order of arguments is reversed.

This generalizes from `elem < value` to `comp(elem, value)` and `value < elem` to `comp(value, elem)`.

Ultimately, there are two choices that we could make when designing this: we could use the *same* comparator everywhere, but for some algorithms the order of arguments is reversed. Or, we could use *different* comparators for every algorithm, depending on what makes sense for that particular algorithm. Using the same comparator everywhere has a lot of advantages - you just use the same comparator:

```
std::vector<int> vs = ...;
std::sort(vs.begin(), vs.end(), std::greater<>{});
auto lo = std::lower_bound(vs.begin(), vs.end(), 5, std::greater<>{});
auto hi = std::upper_bound(vs.begin(), vs.end(), 5, std::greater<>{});
```

Same comparator everywhere, code looks correct, and does the right thing. If we flipped the order of arguments that `upper_bound()` passes to its comparator, we'd have to pass in `std::less<>{}`. Which would just... look wrong.

---

You'll probably be interested in the [Ranges TS](https://ericniebler.github.io/std/wg21/D4128.html#algorithms-should-take-invokable-projections), which solves this problem with invokable projections.

Comment: Writing your own projection is all of `template<class F> auto projected_order( F&& f ) { return [f=std::forward<F>(f)](auto&lhs, auto&rhs)->bool{ return f(lhs) < f(rhs); }; }`, which covers 90% of use cases.  Of course, `overload` also helps, and that takes more code.